# How to Query a Complex Nested Dictionary with Jmespath?

Tags: python-3.x, jmespath

Given the following complexed nested dictionary, which I have converted from my yaml file, I would like query the values of `row_1` and `row_2` keys.

I am using library [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/) to help query with this.

Here what I tried:

```
import jmespath
import pprint

data =  [ 
            { 'includes': 
                            [ 
                                { 
                                    'style': 
                                            [ 
                                                'css/module/sandbox/style.css',
                                                'css/modules/sandbox/mobile.css'
                                            ]
                                },
                                { 'javascript': 
                                            [ 
                                                'js/module/sandbox/script.js',
                                                'js/module/sandbox/mobile.js'
                                            ]
                                 }
                            ]
            },
            { 'row_1': 
                            [ 
                                {
                                    'classes': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary'
                                },
                                { 
                                    'columns': 
                                            [ 
                                                { 
                                                    'col_1': 
                                                            [ 
                                                                {'size': 3},
                                                                { 'classes': 'my-3 text-light ' 'text-center ' 'bg-primary'}
                                                            ]
                                                },
                                                { 
                                                    'col_2': 
                                                            [ 
                                                                {'size': 3},
                                                                { 'classes': 'my-3 text-light ' 'text-center ' 'bg-primary'},
                                                                { 'styles': 
                                                                    [ 
                                                                        { 
                                                                            'div.summary_credit_score': 
                                                                                [ 
                                                                                    { 
                                                                                        'font': '300 ' '12px ' 'open-san, ' 'arial, ' 'Time ' 'New ''Romance'
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                 }
                                            ]
                                }
                            ]
            },
            { 'row_2': 
                            [ 
                                {
                                    'classes': 'my-3 text-light text-center bg-primary'
                                },
                                { 
                                    'columns': 
                                            [ 
                                                { 
                                                    'col_1': 
                                                            [ 
                                                                {'size': 3},
                                                                { 'classes': 'my-3 text-light ' 'text-center ' 'bg-primary'}
                                                            ]
                                                },
                                                { 
                                                    'col_2': 
                                                            [ 
                                                                {'size': 3},
                                                                { 'classes': 'my-3 text-light ' 'text-center ' 'bg-primary'},
                                                                { 'styles': 
                                                                    [ 
                                                                        { 
                                                                            'div.summary_credit_score': 
                                                                                [ 
                                                                                    { 
                                                                                        'font': '300 ' '12px ' 'open-san, ' 'arial, ' 'Time ' 'New ''Romance'
                                                                                    }
                                                                                ]
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                 }
                                            ]
                                }
                            ]
            }
    ]

# get row
rows = jmespath.search('[*].row_*', data)[0] # not success

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(rows)
```

My query above intended to get the values of dictionary that their keys start with `row_`, but does not success. Thanks.

Comment: Mhm, this is not valid JSON data to start with: `{ 'classes': 'my-3 text-light ' 'text-center ' 'bg-primary'}`

Comment: Also JSON uses double quotes, not single ones. Try linting your JSON: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: None of those are relevant for using jmespath in python. In fact, python will just convert them to single wuptes whenever you print anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can't include a wildcard in the name of a key when using jmespath, only for handling values.

Your best bet would be to just use a dict comprehension.

```
rows = {k:v for data_dict in data for k, v in data_dict.items() if 'row' in k}
```